# is there a way in asp.net mvc 4 to create an Index Action inside Base Controller and Share the view of this Action to multiple Controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this controller:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
    {    
        public ActionResult Index(string controller)
        {
            TemplateMasterModel model = new TemplateMasterModel()
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

I created a view for baseController Index Action

It is located in Views/Base/Index.cshtlm

code:

```
@model Reports.Models.TemplateMasterModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = @Model.Title;
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@Html.Partial("TemplateRptMaster",Model)

@section scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/rptFormSubmit")
}
```

I want to know if there is a way to use this Index view for others Controller that inherits BaseController, it is returning the following error:

> The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine
>   supports the searched locations. The following locations were
>   searched:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just put the index.cshtml view into the Shared folder as well. If you dont want to clutter up your shared folder, and want some other scheme, you will have to write your own view engine, which sounds more complicated than it is... here's a link to do that: http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/NcJP200113-Custom-Razor-View-Engine-for-C

Comment: Thanks man, it's wonderfull, all i did was write my own view engine for my especific MVC Area, it worked with no trouble.

**My code:**

` public class MyViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
    {
        public MyViewEngine()
        {
            AreaViewLocationFormats = new[]
             {
                "~/Areas/Rpts/Views/Base/Index.cshtml"
             };
        }
    } `

The engine must be registered in Global.asax File.

**This way:**

`ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new MyViewEngine());`